django uploaded images from admin panel not displayed in the homepage
i created a django project to upload images both from the user interface and from the admin panel. but when uploading images from user interface, the images are not uploaded to the media folder.and also not shown in the homepage. but when uploading from the admin panel, the images are uploaded to the media folder correctly but in the home page the images are not shown. this problem is with the images only. other fields are correctly displayed like the title, price aand so on. tell me how to fix my issue. these are my code snippets.
user interface uploading code
      <div class="layout__body">
        <form
          class="form"
          action=""
          method="POST"
          enctype="multipart/form-data"
        >
          {% csrf_token %}

          <div class="form__group">
            <label for="post_category">Enter a Category</label>
            <input
              required
              type="text"
              value="{{post.category.name}}"
              name="category"
              list="category-list"
            />
            <datalist id="category-list">
              <select id="post_category">
                {% for category in categories %}
                <option value="{{category.name}}">{{category.name}}</option>
                {% endfor %}
              </select>
            </datalist>
          </div>

          <div class="form__group">
            <label for="post_name">Post Title</label>
            {{form.title}}
          </div>

          <div class="form__group">
            <label for="post_image">Post Image</label>
            {{form.image}}
          </div>

          <div class="form__group">
            <label for="post_price">Post Price</label>
            {{form.price}}
          </div>

          <div class="form__action">
            <a class="btn btn--dark" href="{{request.META.HTTP_REFERER}}"
              >Cancel</a
            >
            <button class="btn btn--main" type="submit">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </form>

views.py for post creation
@staff_member_required
@login_required(login_url='login')
def create_post(request):
    form = PostForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        category_name = request.POST.get('category')
        category,created_at = Category.objects.get_or_create(name = category_name)
        
        Post.objects.create(
            host=request.user,
            category=category,
            title=request.POST.get('title'),
            image=request.FILES.get('post_image'),
            price = request.POST.get('price')
        )
        print(request.FILES)
        return redirect('home')

    context = {'form': form, 'categories': categories}
    return render(request, 'base/post_form.html', context)

and models.py
def post_image_path(instance, filename):
    # Customize the upload path for posts based on the posting admin's username and category
    if instance.host and instance.category:
        # Create a folder based on the posting admin's username
        username_folder = instance.host.username
        # Create a subfolder based on the category name
        category_folder = instance.category.name.replace(' ', '_').lower()
    else:
        username_folder = 'unknown_user'
        category_folder = 'uncategorized'

    # Construct the full upload path
    upload_path = os.path.join('uploads', 'posts', username_folder, category_folder, filename)
    print("Upload path: ",upload_path)
    return upload_path


class Post(models.Model):
    host = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='participants',blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=post_image_path)  # Adjust upload path as needed
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    # content = models.TextField()  # Add content field for post body
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)  # Auto-populate creation date

    total_likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-updated_at','-created_at']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

and the home page to display the images
        <div>
          <a href="{% url 'post' post.pk %}">
            <img
              src="{{ post.post_image.url }}"
              alt="{{ post.title }}"
              class="responsive-img"
            />
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class="Post">
          <a
            href="{% url 'user-profile' post.host.id %}"
            class="roomListRoom__author"
          >
            <div class="avatar avatar--small">
              <img src="{{post.host.avatar.url}}" />
            </div>
            <span>@{{post.host.username}}</span>
          </a>
        </div>

        <div>
          <span class="price"><br />ETB {{ post.price }}</span>
        </div>

so please fix this issue
i want to correctly upload the images from the user interface and i want to display the images in the home page

can you share your settings.py

here it is
Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),  # Add your static files directory here
]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'  # Replace BASE_DIR with your project's base directory
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

Because you are assigning an attribute that does not exist in your view:
def create_post(request):
        ...
        Post.objects.create(
            # image=request.FILES.get('post_image')
            image=request.FILES.get('image'),
        )
        ...
    return render(request, 'base/post_form.html', context)

Also, calling the wrong field on your template:
...
<a href="">
  <img
    src="{{ post.image.url }}"
    alt="{{ post.title }}"
    class="responsive-img"
  />
</a>
...

Aside from that, make sure that you are serving your static files.

fixed that bug but did not work yet

Then, what is the issue now?

1, the images i posted through the user interface did not upload to media directory     2, when i upload images using admin panel, the images uploaded to media directory but they did not appear in the home page     no error recieved just as it was


We just fixed that. 2) Not displaying when its uploaded means you are not serving the files properly. Share your forms.py and main app urls.py, please.


from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Post, User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
model = Post
fields = 'all'
exclude = ['host','participants']
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class UserForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
model = User
fields = ['avatar', 'name', 'username' , 'email', 'bio']
this is forms.py


urlpatterns = [
path('create_post/', views.create_post, name='create_post'),  # Path for creating a post
path('update_post/<str:pk>/', views.update_post, name='update_post'),
path('delete_post/<str:pk>/', views.delete_post, name="delete_post"),
path('delete_message/<str:pk>/', views.delete_message, name="delete_message"),

] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

oh now this error happens the image attribute has no file associated with it what is the problem

You could've just appended to your question...urls.py seems okay. But on forms.py you need to fix PostForm fields to fields = '__all__'. (you shouldn't even been able to runserver like that). Also, either use __all__ or exclude, doesn't make sense to use both.

The problem means exactly what it says. That no file has been associated with the image attribute...
